Help geo locate this specific spot
I came across this picture online and the info I could obtain is that it is near the Taipei Songshan Airport.
However I couldn't find the specific spot on google maps. Any idea what is the specific spot? I would like to take that picture one day.


It's literally written on the picture. 北安路458巷, the green sign on right side. Copy this into google map: 10491台湾台北市中山區北安路458巷

No comprehendo Chineso!

With a bit of digging around on Google maps, I was able to find the distinctive red cables of that bridge, and identify it as the Dazhi bridge - just north of the airport. Note that this shot was taken with a long telephoto lens, so you'd need to go some distance further up the road to get a matching angle.
